# How can lag be further reduced in Python's tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm building a program in python using tkinter for the GUI.
I've isolated the problem with a simplified example seen below.
The program checks if the webcam is connected and changes a "LED" depending on the status.
It must be able to do so live, meaning as the program is running.
Meanwhile, the user can change a bunch of parameters using sliders and such.
Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import threading

#Main GUI

win= tkinter.Tk(screenName=None,  baseName=None,  className='Main',  useTk=1) #Création de la fenêtre dans l'objet 'win'
win.title('Main') #Titre de la fenêtre
win.geometry('500x200') #Grosseur de la fenêtre
# win.state('zoomed')

#Accès aux Assets
win.iconbitmap('../Assets/black_cat.ico')

#Slider
labelmaster = tkinter.Label(win, text="Master Slider", background='alice blue', font=('bold','22'))
labelmaster.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM)
slidermaster = tkinter.Scale(win, bg="Powder Blue", fg='black', from_="0", to="100",tickinterval="5",resolution="1", orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
slidermaster.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM, fill = tkinter.X)

#Camera checks
cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam1check = cam1.isOpened()

#Indicator Images
greyled = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='../Assets/greyled.png')
greyledsmall = greyled.subsample(2, 2)
redled = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='../Assets/redled.png')
redledsmall = redled.subsample(2, 2)
greenled = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='../Assets/greenled.png')
greenledsmall = greenled.subsample(2, 2)

#Camera Status Indicator
def ledpannel():
    global cam1on, cam1off
    cam1checklabel = tkinter.Label(win, bg="white smoke", text="Caméra #1", font=('bold','22'))
    cam1checklabel.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
    cam1on = tkinter.Label(win, image=greyledsmall,bg="white smoke")
    cam1on.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
    cam1off = tkinter.Label(win, image=greyledsmall,bg="white smoke")
    cam1off.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT)

#Changing images
def checkifonline():
    cam1check = cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened()
    if cam1check is True:
        cam1on.configure(image=greenledsmall)
        cam1off.configure(image=greyledsmall)
    else:
        cam1on.configure(image=greyledsmall)
        cam1off.configure(image=redledsmall)
    
    win.after(2000,checkifonline)

#Threading to avoid lag
def antilag():
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=checkifonline, daemon=True) #Update des LEDs
    thread2.start()
    checkifonline()

ledpannel()
antilag()
win.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the slider very obviously lag despite using threading to isolate the part of the code that checks the status of the camera and updates the leds from the slider.
Just keep moving the slider around and You will see what I mean.
I tried putting the "leds" and the slider in different frames and update only the leds' frame, but the result is the same.

Maybe I'm not using it correctly?
Is there other tips and tricks to reduce lag when using tkinter I am not aware of?

Thank for your help!

Comment: because you're using tkinter, after you trigger something to "change" you can always call `<insert widget here>.update()` or `<insert widget here>.update_idletasks()` to force-update the widget.

Comment: Does `cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened()` take more than a couple hundred ms to execute?

Comment: While the `after` method works as expected to some degree with threading. It doesn't really makes sense to outsource your function out of the mainloop just to reenter it in a different thread. Consider either to use `time.sleep` or just stick with `after` and forget about threading

Comment: Doesn't time.sleep create a delay? The purpose here is to make the changes live, whenever that could occur.
As for cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened(), I'm gonna have to test it out to find out.
I only tried .update(), but I'll test .update_idletasks() to see if I get a better result.

Comment: @Ryan On what, where and when should I insert the .update() ? Tried it on cam1on, cam1off, checkifonline, antilag, but none of these works. If I keep the .after with it, it's just equivalent.

Comment: @BryanOakley Looks like that might be the problem. I added {import timeit} and {print(timeit.timeit(setup = 'import cv2', stmt = 'cam1check = cv2.VideoCapture(1).isOpened()', number = 10), 'seconds')
} to the code and the result was around 22.7 seconds! Any idead how I can get around that problem ?